# Why the target OS is set to HP-UX instead of Linux in this elf file?

Tags: c, linux, elf

From [this wiki](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#/File_header):
[image]

It states that the number at offset 7 identifies the target OS.

I've compiled a c program for a linux machine and inspected the `elf header` (first 64 bytes) of the resulting file:

```
> xxd -l 64 helloworld
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0300 3e00 0100 0000 8012 0000 0000 0000  ..>.............
00000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 183f 0000 0000 0000  @........?......
00000030: 0000 0000 4000 3800 0d00 4000 1f00 1e00  ....@.8...@.....
```

Why am I getting `01` for the 7th byte? Shouldn't it be `03`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why am I getting 01 for the 7th byte?

Byte at offset 7 is 8th byte, and it is `0`, ie `System V`. The `1` is for `e_ident[EI_VERSION]` which is set to 1 for "set to 1 for the original and current version of ELF".

```
7f45 4c46 0201 0100 ...
                 ^^ - OSABI
               ^^ - VERSION
            ^^  DATA
          ^^ CLASS
^^^^^^^^^ - MAG{0..3}
```

> Shouldn't it be 03?

As explained by your link "it is often set to 0 regardless of the target platform".

Comment: Why is it `System V` and not `Linux`?

Comment: @Klaus Shouldn't the elf magic be only 4 bytes (7f45 4c46)?

Comment: @StackExchange123 The explanation would be like: because the target operating system ABI needed by this executable is needed to be compatible with SystemV, not specifically with Linux.

Comment: @Klaus No, he doesn't. Magic number has 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

From the binutils header description:

```
  35 #define EI_MAG0     0   /* File identification byte 0 index */
  36 #define ELFMAG0        0x7F /* Magic number byte 0 */
  37 
  38 #define EI_MAG1     1   /* File identification byte 1 index */
  39 #define ELFMAG1         'E' /* Magic number byte 1 */
  40 
  41 #define EI_MAG2     2   /* File identification byte 2 index */
  42 #define ELFMAG2         'L' /* Magic number byte 2 */
  43 
  44 #define EI_MAG3     3   /* File identification byte 3 index */
  45 #define ELFMAG3         'F' /* Magic number byte 3 */
  46 
  47 #define EI_CLASS    4   /* File class */
  48 #define ELFCLASSNONE          0 /* Invalid class */
  49 #define ELFCLASS32        1 /* 32-bit objects */
  50 #define ELFCLASS64        2 /* 64-bit objects */
  51 
  52 #define EI_DATA     5   /* Data encoding */
  53 #define ELFDATANONE       0 /* Invalid data encoding */
  54 #define ELFDATA2LSB       1 /* 2's complement, little endian */
  55 #define ELFDATA2MSB       2 /* 2's complement, big endian */
  56 
  57 #define EI_VERSION  6   /* File version */
  58 
  59 #define EI_OSABI    7   /* Operating System/ABI indication */
  60 #define ELFOSABI_NONE         0 /* UNIX System V ABI */
  61 #define ELFOSABI_HPUX         1 /* HP-UX operating system */
  62 #define ELFOSABI_NETBSD       2 /* NetBSD */
  63 #define ELFOSABI_GNU          3 /* GNU */
  64 #define ELFOSABI_LINUX        3 /* Alias for ELFOSABI_GNU */
  65 #define ELFOSABI_SOLARIS      6 /* Solaris */
  66 #define ELFOSABI_AIX          7 /* AIX */
  67 #define ELFOSABI_IRIX         8 /* IRIX */
  68 #define ELFOSABI_FREEBSD      9 /* FreeBSD */
  ...
```

But why someone should look for bits in an elf header? If you want a textual header description use a tool!

> readelf -h a.out

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4013f0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          486392 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         11
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         38
  Section header string table index: 37
```

Comment: The one which "readelf" provides! If you are in doubt, take a look of binutils source files, there will find the header struct for current elf files. But again: If you are working on some kind of machine, use the tools which are available. If you are able to compile, you have the reader tools typically also available.